# Gnuplot: color for stacked histogram bars

Tags: gnuplot

I want to create this histogram with gnuplot:
[image: sample]

I used the 6th example from http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html

datafile has the next structure:

> Region    Austria Hungary ...
>
> 1891-1900 234081 181288   ...
>
> 1901-1910 668209 808511 ...
>
> ...

https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/blob/master/demo/immigration.dat

The minimal script I've got here
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.6.gnu

Is it possible to set the custom color for periods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, nevertheless one could prescribe the colors manually by overriding the default linetypes:

```
set lt 1 lc rgb 'red'
set lt 2 lc rgb 'orange-red'
set lt 3 lc rgb 'orange'
set lt 4 lc rgb 'yellow'
set lt 5 lc rgb 'green'
set lt 6 lc rgb 'blue'
set lt 7 lc rgb 'dark-blue'
set lt 8 lc rgb 'violet'

plot 'immigration.dat' using 6 ti col, '' using 12 ti col, '' using 13 ti col, '' using 14:key(1) ti col
```

In combination with your minimal script, this produces:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

But is it possible to have a color value inside data file?

Comment: Thanks again, I found a workaround with passing variables to my script and your solution:

`gnuplot -e "color1=xxx" my_script`

Inside myscript:

`set lt 1 lc rgb color1`
and so on...